# Selected object automatically brought to front

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, fabricjs

Whenever I select an item in the canvas , it is automatically brought to the top leaving all the objects behind. Is there any way I can stop this from happening?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Set the "**preserveObjectStacking**" property of the **fabricjs** canvas to true to stop the bringtofront on selected objects.

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
canvas.preserveObjectStacking = true;
```

Comment: well, why  cant the image be moved anymore with this setting? i can select it (see markers and stuff) and it stays on the right z-index but moving is not possible (resize, rotate is working)

Comment: There is an extra space in your answer `canvas.preserveObjectStacking = true;`